# Ajax multiple onchange dynamic dependent select box

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

would really appreciate your help on below issue. I have 3 dynamic dependent dropdowns. Scheme 1 is working when: Click Dropdown (Dd) 1=>Values change in Dd2=>Values change in Dd3. But I need Dd3 to be also dependent on Dd1 & Dd2.
I have ajax code and suppose it has mistakes:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#country', '#state').on('change',function(){
 var countryID = $('#country').val();
 var stateID = $('#state').val();
 if(countryID, stateID){
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url:'search_city.php',
 data: "country_id="+countryID+"&state_id="+stateID,
 success:function(html){
 $('#city').html(html);
 }
 });

 }else{

 $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');

 }
 })
 });
```

ADDING PHP FILE:

```
  <?php 
  include('connect.php');  

  if (isset($_POST["country_id"] || isset($_POST["state_id"]))) {

  $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE country_id = 
  ".$_POST['country_id']." AND state_id = ".$_POST['state_id']." ORDER BY 
  city_name");

  $rowCount = $query->num_rows;


  if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option 
    value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
    }
    }else{

   echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
   }
   }


   ?>
```

Comment: I have "Select state first" value in Dd3

Comment: seems it doesn't react on previous 2 selections => ignores php file with DB connection

Comment: No, they are not null

Comment: Still the same...but I also think that mistake is somewhere here:

Comment: it should be $('#country, #state').on('change',function(){

Comment: Yeees, you are right! Thank you! Now my Dd3 is empty, need to check my php file.. Would you also check it? Thank you again!

Comment: Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Is the code [indented properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Are there enough paragraphs? If it doesn't, work on it until you feel like it is easy to read and understand. Also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to write good questions. This will increase your chances of someone actually answering your question a great deal!

Comment: @want2learn Can I get reference about price estimation using the dynamic dependent select box? like > USA (Country) -> Alaska (State) -> Shipping Cost : $80